# Can a FortiGate's "software switch" defined as FortiLink be also used with 3rd-party devices?

Tags: networking, switch, fortigate, fortinet

I need to connect a couple of FortiSwitches to a FortiGate HA pair over FortiLink.
I'm thinking to define a "software switch" object as FortiLink, rather than LAG or concrete port - for flexibility of changes. Theoretically, this is [supposed to work](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortiswitch/7.0.8/devices-managed-by-fortios/173260/configuring-fortilink):

> You can configure FortiLink on a logical interface: link-aggregation group (LAG), hardware switch, or software switch.

The question is: will I also be able to connect non-Fortinet devices, servers or 3rd-party switches, to other ports joined to the same "software switch"?